# Скролл к якорям при нажатии на пробел(space). Нужно убрать прокрутку при нажатии много раз на пробел(space)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Код делает прокрутку к якорям при нажатии на пробел(space). Но есть один баг. Когда нажимаешь много раз и быстро пробел оно скролит столько раз сколько ты нажал пробел. То есть ты уже ничего не нажимаешь(пробел), а скрол идет дальше. 
Нужно, чтобы работало как у https://aic.ru/

Как это исправить?

> ```
> var i = 0;
>
> $(window).on("keypress", function(e) {
>   if (e.keyCode == 0 || e.keyCode == 32) {
>     var $a = $('.anchor');
>     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $a.eq( i ).offset().top}, 350);
>     i = ( i === $a.length - 1 ) ? ( 0 ) : ( i + 1 );
>
>   }
> });
> ```

Comment: Просто уберите это: || e.keyCode == 32  из условия

Comment: Тогда скрипт не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var i = 0;

$(window).on("keydown", function(e) {

  if ($('html, body').is(':animated')) { // <--
    return;                              // <--
  }                                      // <--

  if (e.keyCode == 0 || e.keyCode == 32) {
    var $a = $('.anchor');
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $a.eq( i ).offset().top
    }, 350);
    i = ( i === $a.length - 1 ) ? ( 0 ) : ( i + 1 );
  }
});
```

```css
div{height:10000px;border:1px solid #000}
.anchor{margin-top:2000px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p id="anchor1" class="anchor">anchor1</p>
  <p id="anchor2" class="anchor">anchor2</p>
  <p id="anchor3" class="anchor">anchor3</p>
  <p id="anchor4" class="anchor">anchor4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Просто бомба! Огромное спасибо!